# Can the data type for a generic List<T> be implied?

Tags: .net, collections, c#-4.0, ienumerable

Is there an implicit way to tell a generic collection to use the `Type` of the incoming `IEnumerable<T>` data?

Assume any Type can be incoming because it might have been obscured, for example, through IQueryable and might contain an anonymous Type.

```
var enumerableThings = //... enumerable<T> obtained from somewhere.
```

The point is T is unknown.

I want to create a `List<T>` of the primary Type of the enumerable thing:

```
var listOfThoseThings = new List<???>(enumerableThings);
```

There are many interesting mechanisms in C#/.NET.  I wouldn't be surprised to find the ability to carry out this task; however at the moment a concise way evades me.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is why the [`ToList()` extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261.aspx) exists.

```
var listOfThoseThings = enumerableThings.ToList();
```

Unlike the `List<T>` constructor, it can use type inference to implcitly specify the generic parameter.

Comment: This will of course enumerate the IEnumerable when called, which could have implications if your enumerable is linq-sql or any other long running set.

Comment: @asawyer: That's true for any `List<T>`, no matter how you create it.

Comment: Yep, just noting it for @JohnK. Would hate to find out he didn't realize this and ended up enumermating a linq to sql query a dozen times in a function or something :)

Comment: Already been through LINQ to SQheLL. :) It pays to read a bit about it before jumping in.

Answer (score 4):

Just to expand on SLaks' (correct) answer.

When you call `ToList`, that's calling the generic method `Enumerable.ToList<T>(IEnumerable<T> source)`. The compiler then uses generic type inference in the normal way to work out `T`.

Note that at the moment although there are calls for `ToList`, `ToDictionary` and `ToArray`, there's no equivalent for `HashSet`. It's very easy to write though:

```
public static class MoreExtensions
{
    public static HashSet<T> ToHashSet<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
    {
        return new HashSet<T>(source);
    }

    public static HashSet<T> ToHashSet<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source,
        IEqualityComparer<T> comparer)
    {
        return new HashSet<T>(source, comparer);
    }
}
```

Doing this sort of thing is the *only* way of constructing an instance of a generic type with a type argument which is an anonymous type, short of generics. It's a good job it's easy :)

Comment: That detail is invaluable. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to directly do this however it can be indirectly done via method type inference

```
public static List<T> CreateList<T>(IEnumerable<T> enumerableThings)
{
  return new List<T>(enumerableThings);
}

var listOfThoseThings = CreateList(enumerableThings);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
static List<T> GetList<T>(IEnumerable<T> enumerableThings)
{
   var listOfThoseThings = new List<T>(enumerableThings);
   return listOfThoseThings;
}
```